# How to repeatedly pipe input between commands until condition on output applies?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a bash script that repeatedly pipes output between two processes, until the output contains some special characters.

Consider these two Python scripts:

**script1.py**

```
from sys import stdin
for line in stdin.readline():
    if line.isdigit():
        print int(line) + 3
```

**script2.py**

```
from sys import stdin
for line in stdin.readline():
    if line.isdigit():
        print int(line) - 1
```

and the following execution

```
$ echo 0|python script1.py|python script2.py|python script1.py|python script2.py 
4
```

Can a Bash script be created, that executes the two scripts and passes the output from one as input to the other, until the output of *script1* reaches some certain number?

(I don't want to modify the Python scripts, I'm not actually using them, they were just created  in order to demonstrate what I want to achieve).

Comment: Do you want a bidirectional pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your python script `script2.py` only outputs one number on one line, and you want to execute `python script1.py | python script2.py` until the output number is `4`, here's a recursive way. It uses recursion so you might hit a stackoverflow if there are too many calls:

```
#!/bin/bash

apply_until4() {
   local l
   read l < <(python script1.py | python script2.py)
   if [[ $l = 4 ]]; then
      echo "$l"
      return
   fi
   echo "$l" | apply_until4
}

echo "0" | apply_until4
```

or (with the same logic but slightly different implementation—not pure Bash anymore because of the `cat`, though this could be changed):

```
#!/bin/bash

apply_until4() {
   local l next=apply_until4
   read l < <(python script1.py | python script2.py)
   [[ $l = 4 ]] && next=cat
   echo "$l" | $next
}

echo "0" | apply_until4
```

---

Another possibility without recursion:

```
#!/bin/bash

apply_until4() {
   local l
   read l
   until [[ $l = 4 ]]; do
      read l < <(echo "$l" | python script1.py | python script2.py)
   done
   echo "$l"
}

echo "0" | apply_until4
```

---

- In both methods, the idea is to read the output of the combo `python script1.py | python script2.py` and if the output is not `4`, feed it to the combo again.
- The

  ```
  read l < <(python script.py | python script2.py)
  ```

  statement can be changed to

  ```
  l=$(python script.py | python script2.py)
  ```

  and, similarly, the

  ```
  read l < <(echo "$l" | python script1.py | python script2.py)
  ```

  statement can be changed to

  ```
  l=$(echo "$l" | python script1.py | python script2.py)
  ```

  with the difference that the `read` will discard all leading and trailing spaces, if any.

Answer (score 2):

A safer approach that could prevent fork bomb:

```
function piper {
    read
    if [[ $REPLY == 4 ]]; then
        echo 4
    elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ && $REPLY -lt 4 ]]; then
        echo "$REPLY" | python script1.py | python script2.py | piper
    fi
}

echo 0 | piper
```

Comment: Not conceptually different from my recursive answer (and will have the same flaws wrt stackoverflows). What do you mean by safer? is it just because you check the output of the combo to be a word formed of digits? or did I miss something else? in what will my answer create a fork bomb? (potential infinite loop, yes, fork bomb, I don't see any).

Comment: Also, the regex is probably overkill, a glob would do just fine; and your test `[[ $REPLY -lt 4 ]]` is either wrong or useless.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I actually find `[[ $REPLY -lt 4 ]]` a little inefficient but I was lazy to calculate it. Can you prove why it is useless? About the fork bomb, `echo "$l" | apply_until4` could produce infinite subshells. And why is the regex overkill? What exact expression could have been enough? Oh yes with a -more- careful examination, `$REPLY == [[:digit:]]` would seem to be enough granting the target would not be increased.

Comment: `echo "$l" | apply_until4` _could_ produce infinite subshells, when given wrong initial conditions _in the case of the toy scripts given by the OP_. The goal in my answer was to _show concepts that can be used to achieve what the OP was up to_, not to _craft a 100% bullet proof script around what is clearly a demonstration case_. That being said, the other points of our discussion become irrelevant. Though, 2 things: `[[ $REPLY = +([[:digit:]]) ]]` to avoid regex; this safety guard makes it impossible to initialize with negative numbers: `[[ $REPLY = ?(-)+([[:digit:]]) ]]` for a fix

Comment: Yes that's the obvious reason why I did it. To avoid -possible- fork bomb just in case the OP mistakenly sends a false initial input. You also need `==` not just `=` if you're going to check with glob patterns. And since you also use extended patterns you need to initialize `extglob`. I always favor ext. glob and had the first pattern check with it but I just chose to go regex to reduce the number of lines and prevent redundant shopt calls.

Comment: The documentation is not really clear about this, but extended globs do work on the right hand side of an equality inside `[[ ... ]]`, even if `extglob` is unset. Also, `=` is fine inside `[[ ... ]]`. But yes, the doc is not very clear on this.

Comment: Starting 4.1 it does. `extglob` option seems to be already just for pathname expansion and no longer about `[[ ... ]]`.